# Express: send Content-Type on 304 Not Modified

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mime-types

```
app.use(express.static('./public'));
```

**Express** sends a valid `mime` by using the snippet above - but **only once**.  After the client cached the response, every request returning a `304 Not Modified`, will be answered without any `Content-Type` header.

Is express able to send a `Content-Type` on cached responses? Or is it a bad idea in general?

Background: Our beloved IE seems to demand a valid `mime` (*CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch*) for `asynchronously` requested CSS files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 304 response has no body and the purpose of the `content-type` header is to identify the response body, so it doesn't make sense to have `content-type` with a 3XX response. Can you point to a specific reproducible sequence of request/responses and an exact IE version to reproduce your problem? I've never heard anyone complaining about this issue before, so I suspect this is not actually your issue.

Comment: Turns out, the real problem was caused by IEs different approach to render paths of `<link>` elements in relation with an ending `/` at  `<base href>` - thus causing my `backend` to send a text/html (wrong) mime. Thank you for helping me to think in another direction!